# Intercept connection pooling of Datasource connections in JEE container

Tags: java, hibernate, datasource, wildfly, sqldatasource

is it possible to intercept the connection pooling mechanism of a DataSource in a JEE container?

For (un)setting some information on the connection's context I'm searching for a way to intercept the pooling mechanism so that I know when and which connection is put back into the pool.

So does anyone know a (common) way to do this?

**Some additional info:**

- The application runs on Wildfly
- Using Hibernate for ORM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option `connection-listener` in datasource configuration can be the solution.

> **connection-listener:**
>
> An `org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.spi.listener.ConnectionListener` that
>   provides a possible to listen for connection activation and
>   passivation in order to perform actions before the connection is
>   returned to the application or returned to the pool

You can create a custom implementation of `org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.spi.listener.ConnectionListener` and deploy it as a module to do that you want.

Comment: Thanks, I've missed that option.